# Creating linux user on host from container

Tags: linux, docker, namespaces, linux-namespaces

Is there a way to share the user namespace with a docker container, so that linux users I create in the container will exist on the host?

Comment: Refer this Article, might be helpful to you [sharing user namespace](https://docs.datadoghq.com/security_platform/default_rules/cis-docker-1.2.0-5.30/)

Comment: You'd need to give the container access to write the host's `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow` file; using `sudo` and not Docker would be easier.